# If I delete Crossbrowse from my computer, will the bookmarks go with it?

Tags: google-chrome, virus, bookmarks, cross-browser

Crossbrowse is a virus program that came with a file that I downloaded from the internet. It did not delete my Google  Chrome, but it replaced its icon and it starts popping up automatically. It has also accessed to all my Chrome information, notably the bookmarks. If I delete it from my computer but leave Chrome, will the bookmarks stay? Thank you :)

Comment: Why don't you export your bookmarks first?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes. 20 minutes ago I deleted the virus crossbrowse along with other suspicious downloads. As soon as I deleted crossbrowse google crome came back. When it asked me if I wanted to uninstall crossbrowse there was a box to check and it said "restore your browsing history" I left it unchecked to be safe so that could be why. Hope I helped! Oh and if you see Winfix 10 or Winfix 10 pro delete that ASAP! Its not good. Again, I hope I helped! :)